# Why Firefox 60.0.2 (64bit) is much faster when I turn off IPv6 inside of it?

Tags: firefox, ipv6

Pages as Facebook and Youtube in Firefox became much faster after I have set true network.dns.disableIPv6 in about:config. Why?

Speed became very similar as in case of Google Chrome was originally without any fine tune.

Thanks & br,
Halacs

Comment: You may have broken IPv6 in your ISP or your home router. Try a firmware update of the home router.

Comment: I have a Mikrotik router with the most recent firmware.ipv6-test.com is reachable without any warning. Do you have any concrete idea what should I check there?

Comment: Maybe your DNS servers? It's hard to know for sure.